# Why am I getting "Authentication failure" when running the "su" command?

Tags: command-line, su

I am having problems with the `su` command. I know my password and I am typing it correctly, but `su` indicates `Authentication failure`.

So I checked on the internet and then went into recovery mode and changed my user's password to what I was entering before. Even now, entering the same password on `su` gives me `Authentication failure`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`su` asks for the root password. Since Ubuntu doesn't set a root password by default, you can't use it to become root.

Instead, to become root, use `sudo -i` with your personal password.

Comment: I admit I tend to use `sudo bash` but your incantation makes me want to use `su sudo` or maybe `su su sudo`.

Comment: `sudo su` is not the recommended way - use `sudo -i` instead.

Comment: Try https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=axDObUgsuZQ instead, it will help you to solve the authentication failure error on su root

Answer (score 17):

`su` asks for the password of the account you're trying to login. It's usage (simplified):

```
su username
```

When omitting `username`, the username default to `root`. Since the root password is disabled by default on Ubuntu, no password will be valid. The preferred way to run root commands is not through a su shell, but with sudo as in:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

Answer (score 11):

[The `root` account in Ubuntu is disabled by default.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) This is to say that it has no password (which is different from it having a *blank* password) and no attempt to authenticate with root's password will succeed. Therefore, `su` or `su -` will not work.

Instead, use [`sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/sudo.8.html) to run a command as root:

```
sudo command...
```

If you want a root shell like you get with `su`, run:

```
sudo -s
```

If you want a root shell like you get with `su -`, run:

```
sudo -i
```

Answer (score 4):

when you need to login as one of your non-login userids say `git` ( has no pwd)

```
su - git
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
```

SOLUTION - use this syntax to login as userid `git`

```
sudo su - git
```

Comment: It's not a different syntax, but an entirely different program.  In addition, sudo itself support logging in as another user, e.g. the equivalent command would be `sudo -iu git`.

Answer (score 3):

I came across an OS, Minibian, where the setuid bit was missing from `/bin/su`, causing this error, even if the password of the root account was enabled.

On Linux, the only way to become root is to execute a setuid-root file. When you run `sudo` or `su`, their setuid bit is set, so the process' effective user becomes root, then they do the authentiaction already as root! If it fails they exit.

Anyway, here are the symptoms and the fix:

```
$ su
Password:
su: authentication failure
$ sudo su
# ls -l /bin/su
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 31092 Jun  5  2012 /bin/su
# chmod u+s /bin/su
# ls -l /bin/su
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 31092 Jun  5  2012 /bin/su
```

Note the difference: `rwx` before, `rws` after.

Comment: I don't really see how a bug on a completely different Linux distribution is related to Ubuntu...?

Comment: I faced this on Ubuntu Trusty as well! I dont know how I landed up in that situation, but this answer was a life saver! :) `/bin/su` should have permissions `4755` if not, get weird errors like `Account expired` !!

Answer (score 1):

`su` asks for the root password.

You can set a root password while you're root (by giving `sudo su`, providing that you are on the `sudoers` file), by giving the command `passwd` and setting a new password.

This is not recommend it for various reasons, though.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because the entry for that user was missing in `/etc/shadow`.

I had copied to another test server all entries in `/etc/passwd` with ID higher than 1000 along with `/etc/group` but forgot `/etc/shadow`. So everytime I did `su` with any of those users I would get that error. After adding the missing entry in `/etc/shadow` the error would stop appearing.

For example `/etc/shadow`:

```
myusername:*:16992:0:99999:7:::
```