# Why does su fail with "authentication error"?

Tags: su

I tried to `su` to root so I could install lights, but I get an authentication error when I try:

```
user@host:~$ su
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
```

Comment: Are you following a guide? In Ubuntu the root account is disabled and you may [need sudo instead](http://askubuntu.com/q/6676/169736)

Comment: Just type -sudo su and than the password for your account.

Comment: using su as mentioed by bogdan in the above comment worked for me.(I upvoted the comment)

Answer (score 252):

The root account is disabled by default in Ubuntu, so there is no root password, that's why `su` fails with an authentication error.

Use `sudo` to become root:

```
sudo -i
```

Comment: thanks. I thoguht this error message is caused by wrong password

Comment: in my case, setting the SUID bit solved the issue: `sudo chmod +s /bin/su`

Comment: What is `-i` and what's the difference with `-s`? @Seth

Comment: not working for me.

Comment: @SarfarajSipai Can you elaborate more on what your situation is? What are you trying to do and why are you trying to do it? Thanks :)

Comment: @Seth while print this "sudo -i" i got this "sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin "sudoers_policy"
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be only be writable by owner
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins"

Comment: @SarfarajSipai That's a much bigger problem than we can solve here. Please [ask] a new question providing all the details you can. Thanks!

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks

Answer (score 23):

If `su` doesn't work, *I* do this (in bash):

```
user@host:~$ sudo bash
root@host:~# su
root@host:/home/user#
```

Voila! You are now root!

A shortcut for this would be `sudo su`. In this case given that you are a member of `/etc/sudoers` with all privileges, then you would only need your user's password.

Comment: After `sudo bash` you are already root...

Comment: @edwin After `sudo bash` you are running bash as root, but '~' still points to /home/user or wherever your user's home directory is. So you are not *quite* root. A shortcut for this would be `sudo su`

Comment: For all intends and purposes, you are already root... What's happening is that `sudo` is preserving some environment variables. Instead of `sudo bash` it's better to just use `sudo -i`.

Comment: @edwin In some cases these preserved environment variables matter a lot. So I would argue for *most* intents and purposes you are absolutely right. However, the OP has asked specifically about su to root. I was assuming they knew why they want to do that and that they have a good reason to do it. So I was adding an alternate path to becoming root to the discussion. And here is yet another way: `sudo -i` then `su`. But I would *totally* agree that in most cases just using sudo should be fine. That is what I usually do. Unless I **need** root. Then I use `su`.

Comment: `sudo -i` already is enough. Seriously, you just `sudo su` or `sudo -i`, this is enough to become root (no need to "su" again)...

Comment: @edwin: Ok man. You are right. Have an awesome day!

Comment: up voted for maintaining a positive attitude

Comment: sudo -i  is correct, and use ctrl+d if you need to logout of the root account.

Answer (score 13):

You are getting `Authentication failure` because you are trying to become root which is [disabled by default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6676/why-is-there-no-option-to-login-as-root) in all versions of Ubuntu. This can be easily circumvented in two ways:

1. [Enabling the root account.](https://askubuntu.com/q/44418/169736) This can be achieved by setting up a password.
2. Instead of `su` use `sudo -i` or better yet, append to any command `sudo` in the way of:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   [sudo] password for braiam:
   ```

I wouldn't recommend enabling root, since it could raise a security concern, for example, if you use any service exposed to the web.

Answer (score 13):

Open root with `sudo -s` and when it's in this mode type:

> passwd

Then, choose password. This password will be for `su` command.

Answer (score 4):

Use `sudo your_command` in place of su.
 ie

```
sudo apt-get install "program to install"
```