# Why doesn't the 'su' command work in Ubuntu but does in other Linux distros?

Tags: command-line, sudo, su

When I type the `su` command in a terminal I get

```
 su: Authentication failure
```

Why doesn't this work in Ubuntu? I have tried this command in another Linux distro (Parrot OS) and it does work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because in Ubuntu, by default, root has no password.

Without arguments, `su` means "switch user to root" and to do that you have to enter root's password, not your own. Unless you give root a password, it doesn't have one, so you can't literally log in as root.

Here's some background:

> In the Unix world, there has always been a larger division between
>   regular users and administrators, owing to the multiuser heritage of
>   Unix. The approach taken in Unix is to grant superuser privileges only
>   when needed. To do this, the su and sudo commands are commonly used.
>
> Up until a few years ago, most Linux distributions relied on su for
>   this purpose. su didn't require the configuration that sudo
>   required, and having a root account is traditional in Unix. This
>   introduced a problem. Users were tempted to operate as root
>   unnecessarily. In fact, some users operated their systems as the root
>   user exclusively, since it does away with all those annoying
>   “permission denied” messages. This is how you reduce the security of
>   a Linux system to that of a Windows system. Not a good idea.
>
> When Ubuntu was introduced, its creators took a different tack. By default,
>   Ubuntu disables logins to the root account (by failing to set a
>   password for the account), and instead uses sudo to grant superuser
>   privileges. The initial user account is granted full access to
>   superuser privileges via sudo and may grant similar powers to
>   subsequent user accounts.

~ [The Linux Command Line](http://www.linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php)

You can use `su` to switch user, if you know the password of the user to switch to, for example, I can `su pixie` to log in as my backup user.

Normally though, you should use `sudo` and your own password to authenticate, or to start a root shell, use `sudo -i`

Comment: Technically, `su` means "switch user" (and _defaults_ to root.) It does not mean "super user."

Comment: I never said it meant super user!

Comment: Well, technically is not that root has no password, root login is *disabled*. This is different. You can have an enable account where the password is literally empty (though you may have to modify the default restrictions on passwords). A disabled login will have a `!` prepended to the password hash, since the representation used for the hash cannot contain `!`s you have that all inputs produce an invalid authentication.

Comment: @Bakuriu A literally empty password is still a password.

Answer (score 9):

That is because in the other distros when installing them they usually will prompt you to set a `root` password as well as a user account password.  Ubuntu does not ask for the `root` password during setup, only a user account password of a user that will have `sudo` access leaving the `root` account disabled in Ubuntu.  If you want to have this enabled, set a password for the `root` account that will enable the `root` account allowing for the `su` command to work.

```
sudo passwd root
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

Briefly

Root account is disabled by default in Ubuntu, hence doesn't have password set, so it causes that authentication failure

To become root in Ubuntu, you can use this

```
sudo -i
```

Answer (score 4):

By default, `su` has no password. When you run that command, you're trying to log into the hidden `root` account on your machine. I'm going to assume that Parrot OS either uses the `root` account or sets its password to yours, because otherwise it wouldn't work.

If you want to use `su`, then you can run `sudo passwd root` and set the password you want to use to log in with `su`. This will also enable the root user as a full account user, however, so I don't recommend it.

Instead, when you need persistent root privileges in that shell, use `sudo su`. This will allow you to become root by using your own account and password. `sudo -i` will have the same effect (and people will recommend you use this instead).

Answer (score 1):

The `su` (super user authentication) is not configure for security and safe administration. When you install ubuntu you gets all administration access with `sudo`    as 'fist user' [1000]. The 'root' privilege with `sudo` . The 'guest users' [1001,1002,1003 etc] will not be able to do super user authentication with `sudo`. Admin[user with 'root' privilege]   need to add other 'guest user' to 'group' for superuser privileges.

You can do all `su`authentication command with `sudo` in Ubuntu.

For other linux distributions system reads 'root user' as [500] and 'first user' as [501].

`su`authentication gives you access to modify and delete any file or folder as root user.

You can login as superuser by

```
sudo -i
```

However, it is not recommended.

Comment: No, `su` is not "super use authentication", it's "Substitute User". Check `man su`: "su - run a command with substitute user and group ID". Another minor nitpick: The `root` user has an ID of 0 on practically all UNIX-es.