# su: Authentication failure

Tags: authentication, su

I have downloaded the Eset Nod32 Antivirus from its website, and I got a `eset_nod32av_64bit_en.linux` file. I have right-clicked on it, Properties - Permissions, and checked the Allow executing file as program option. Then I was able to run the program. The Installer starts and it asks for my root password. I enter it correctly, but then I get the following error message: `su: Authentication failure`. What can I do with this to install the Nod32?

Comment: possible duplicate of [su command + authentication failure](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34329/su-command-authentication-failure)

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu DOES use `sudo` instead of `su` but this doesn't really solve the problem long term.  In order to solve this problem for good you need to change the `su` password.  Unfortunately to change the `su` password in Ubuntu you can't just use the `passwd` command. You need to use a combination of `sudo` with `passwd` like this:

```
user@user-ubuntu1:~$ sudo passwd
[sudo] password for user: # enter your sudo password here
Enter new UNIX password: # enter the password you want for your su password here
Retype new UNIX password: # reenter your new su password
passwd: password updated successfully
```

And there you have it - no more errors.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu uses sudo

so

```
sudo ./eset_nod32av_64bit_en.linux
```

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo for details.