# sudo -s works but su does not in ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, sudo, su

I have Linux Virtual machine (ubuntu 12.04) installed on my Mac OS.

On my terminal,

```
user@192.78.0.1:~$ su
password:
su : Authentication failure

user@192.78.0.1:~$ ls -lth /bin/su
-rwsr-sr-x 1 root root 36K Sep 12 2012 /bin/su
```

But the following works:

```
user@192.78.0.1:~$ sudo ls
[sudo] password for user:
(....lists the directories)

 user@192.78.0.1:~$ sudo -s
 [sudo] password for user:
 root@192.78.0.1:~#
```

Hence the question is,
why `sudo -s` works and logs in as root, while `su` results in authentication failure.
I typed the passwords correctly each time.
Also `sudo ls` works

Comment: possible duplicate of [su command + authentication failure](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34329/su-command-authentication-failure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ubuntu by default, the root user has a disabled password and the mechanism available for general users to use root permissions is sudo.  su with no arguments attempts to change the current user to root, and since it is disabled....

Comment: well it prompts for password `su` and when I type in the correct password, it gives authentication failure

Comment: Exactly.  "su" will still prompt for a password, but since the root account is disabled, you get authentication failure.  "sudo" depends upon your username having sudo permissions.

Comment: but I have seen where `su` and followed by password works. If this feature is possible, how to enable it? or how to undo the disable of root account?

Comment: @brainstorm: see [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/44418/how-to-enable-root-login) question.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do what you are looking for using:

`sudo su`

This works for me on Ubuntu 14.04. Although in general you should be careful about doing this for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
    sudo passwd root
```

to change password for your su user. See if that helps. Then retry using `su` and entering the password you have have have just assinged.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo -i
```

gives a root prompt,

```
passwd
```

changes the root password, from that point you can login as usual.