# Fail with su command

Tags: root

Can someone help me with this fail, I get it when I run the su command.

Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.

Thanks

Comment: Are you running `sudo su` or just `su`? Are you using `ssh`?

Comment: @user68186 I'm running only su without ssh.

Answer (score 1):

**By default, the Root account password is locked in Ubuntu.**

This means that you cannot login as Root directly **or use the su command to become the Root user.** However, since the Root account physically exists it is still possible to run programs with root-level privileges. This is where sudo comes in - it allows authorized users (normally "Administrative" users; for further information please refer to AddUsersHowto) to run certain programs as Root without having to know the root password.

See the [community Ubuntu help on Sudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) for more details. Also see [Why is there no option to login as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6676/why-is-there-no-option-to-login-as-root) for why root is disabled in Ubuntu.

Another related question: [su command + authentication failure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34329/su-command-authentication-failure)

Hope this helps