# su doesn't work from regular or sudoers

Tags: 18.04, sudo, su

I'm trying to use  `su` command to change my identity  on ubuntu 18.04
But from neither regular user to sudoer user or sudoer to regular user it doesnt work!
I get

```
su: Authentication failure
```

The `sudo` works and i can login to my users using ssh (`ssh user@127.0.0.1`) but cannot use `su`

What is the problem?

---

my cammand is simply this:

from user bob:

```
su alice
```

Comment: Providing your actual command may help us to understand, it works for me fine.I suspect it's how you're using it, thus providing your command would help us understand why you're getting the failure message.  (what parameter 'user' are you using, have you enabled 'root' if that's what you want to use)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [su command + authentication failure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34329/su-command-authentication-failure)

Comment: @guiverc  i'm simply using su with user name; please check my edit on question

Comment: @user535733 it is about being root but i have problem with regular users

Comment: @steeldriver thanks, be my guest to correct.

Comment: A couple of possible causes I've seen are (1) missing setuid bit on the su executable (check with `ls -l /bin/su`) and (2) misconfigured `/etc/pam.d/su` file

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

- `sudo passwd alice` to renew password

Or, as a workaround:

- `sudo su - alice`
- `sudo -i` then `su alice`

When switching from root password isn't asked.